# Rails - assigning unique ids to fields for a form that can be edited in multiple modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form that you can access from 2 different modals.

action modal:

```
<%=link_to "Edit",edit_host_public_event_path(id:event.id, modal: "action"),remote:true%>
```

scheduler modal:

```
<%= link_to "#{event.start_time_hour}:00 - #{event.event_name}", edit_host_public_event_path(event, modal: "scheduler"), remote: :true %>
```

Here is the form's js.erb:

```
$("#schedulerModal,#actionModal").html("<%= j render 'new' %>")
```

Here is the view:

```
<% if params[:modal] === "scheduler" %>
  <% f.input :start_time_hour,input_html: { id: "datetimepicker#{no_band_slot_count + 1010}"} %>
<% else %>
  <% f.input :start_time_hour,input_html: { id: "action_datetimepicker#{no_band_slot_count + 1010}"} %>
<% end %>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1010').datetimepicker({ format:'HH'});
    $('#action_datetimepicker1010').datetimepicker({ format:'HH'});
  });
</script>
```

the inputs in each modal are getting their ids assigned properly, but yet the gem is only working on the action modal, not the scheduler.

and actually, before i assigned the 'modal' parameter in the links, only the action modal input worked, and not the scheduler modal, so i've fixed one and broken the other somehow.  It's my first project, thanks!

Comment: seems to be dependent on which is id comes first in the script.

Comment: suggesting that this form then requires a different view for each modal.

Comment: which is a bit of a pain, as the input is actually in a partial.   do I need separate form views, or just separate partials, or both?

Comment: You do know that there are other ways to select elements then with ids? You can use classes. Just use ids when you can actually guarantee that an element is unique. `$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ format:'HH'});`. But you will still have issues with turbolinks and idempotency.

Comment: Thanks!   Class doesn't pick up I assume because it's a bootstrap input.

Comment: Can you show the web server console log for the request/response for each of the modals? Also what does the controller action this is calling look like?

Comment: What do you actually mean by `Class doesn't pick up`? Be more specific. If you are using SimpleForm you would add a class to an input with. `<% f.input :start_time_hour, input_html: { class: 'datetimepicker' } %>`. But as I mentioned earlier you will get issues with idempotency with this appoach if you are using turbolinks as you're running a long standing browser session and not reloading the page on each page view. This is a problem with most jQuery plugins as they are not designed to be idempotent.   https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent